# Recreating phpMyAdmin - jQuery + AJAX - How do I access Arrays within an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, phpmyadmin, children

So I am recreating `phpMyAdmin`. (Yeah, pray for me.)

I need to be able to access the part of the array at the column level.

With `Console.log(_data.rows)` I only `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` aka... an object with a bunch of objects within. One object for each row.

I want to go one level deeper and just have the objects for each row. How would I (for example) `console.log()` only the objects specific to each column in a certain table in my database.

I have gotten this far with `_data.rows` because the object of objects is named, but the individual column objects are not (and they cant be). So how do I get all children objects

So here is my array:

```
var _data = {
    "status":"success",
    "columns":
        [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
            0: Object
                A_I: 1
                blob: 0
                max_length: 1
                multiple_key: 0
                name: "id"
                not_null: 1
                numeric: 1
                primary_key: 1
                table: "admin"
                type: "int"
                unique_key: 0
                unsigned: 1 
                zerofill: 0
                __proto__: Object
             1: Object
             2: Object
             3: Object 
             4: Object
             5: Object
             6: Object
             7: Object
             8: Object
    ]
}
```

I need to get the names of the arrays inside of columns when calling the function like this `window.printFields(_data.columns);`

Here is the entire `AJAX` call.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function getRows(){}

        $('.table').click(function(){
            var selTable = $(this).text();
            getRowStructure(selTable);
        });

        window.getRowStructure = function(tble)
        {
            $.ajax({ 

            url: 'bin/get_row_structure.php',
            data: {table: tble, host: "<?=HOST;?>", user: "<?=USER;?>", pass: "<?=PASS;?>", db: "<?=DB;?>"},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output)
            {
                try
                {
                    var _data = JSON.parse(output);
                    console.log(_data.columns);

                    window.printFields(_data.columns);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                    alert(output);
                }
            }

            });
        }

        window.printFields = function(data)
        {
            for(i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 $('#row_structure_content').append('<div id="someid">' + data + '</div>');
            }
        }

    });
```

All that is getting appended to `#row_structure_length` is:

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] [object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object] [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] [object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object] [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

`[...]` That means you are getting an array, wich is number indexed.

Just do:

```
_data.rows[n]
```

To access the `n-th` element, and so on.

EDIT after your edit, you want to know the **keys** of your object:

```
window.printFields = function(columns)
{

    // iterate all the columns
    for(i=0; i < columns.length; i++) {

      for(var key in columns[i]){

        // columns[i][key] is what you want

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, then I did ` $('#row_structure_content').append('<div id="someid">' + data.columns[i] + '</div>');` and it alerted `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: When I do `$('#row_structure_content').append('<div id="someid">' + data[i] + '</div>');` with `window.printFields(_data.columns);` I still get object...

Comment: I STILL need to go one layer deeper.